# Alternating Frobenius form in Sage

Tags: reference-request, integer-lattices, sagemath, symplectic-linear-algebra, magma-cas

Given an alternating, non-degenerate matrix $A$ over the integers, I need to compute the matrix "closest" to the standard symplectic form that can be obtained from $A$ by an integer change of basis in Sage. This is not the same as the `symplectic_form()` Sage method, as that one is designed to work over a field instead of a ring.

In the [MAGMA documentation](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/280), I found a function that does precisely what I want called `FrobeniusFormAlternating(A)`:

> `FrobeniusFormAlternating(A) : AlgMatElt -> SeqEnum`
>
> Given a non-singular 2n x 2n alternating matrix A over the integers, this function returns the (alternating) Frobenius form F of A. That is, a block matrix F = (matrix(0 & D
>
> - D & 0)), where D is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries, di, satisfying d1 | d2 | ... | dn. The second return value is the change of basis matrix B, such that BA ()<sup>t</sup>B = F.

I cannot find any information on how to compute this matrix (and change of basis), other than the cited work [[Ste97]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771719690142X) (which, as far as I can tell, does not explicitly address the alternating case).

Is there a more standard name for this normal form? Is there a Sage function that computes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `symplectic_form` methods in Sage, one with documentation saying "Find a symplectic form for self if self is an anti-symmetric, alternating matrix defined over a field" and one specifically for integer matrices — see [documentation for integer matrices](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/matrix_integer_dense.html#sage.matrix.matrix_integer_dense.Matrix_integer_dense.symplectic_form). If you specify an integer matrix with `mat = matrix(ZZ, ...)`, the second version should be used.

Comment: Thank you. Nevertheless, there seems to be a difference between the Sage and MAGMA versions, even when using integer matrices. For example, for the matrix

[ 0  0  2  0]
[ 0  0  0  3]
[-2  0  0  0]
[ 0 -3  0  0]

Sage leaves the matrix unchanged, while MAGMA gives

[ 0  0  1  0]
[ 0  0  0  6]
[-1  0  0  0]
[ 0 -6  0  0]

The second output is more "standard" in the sense that each entry of the diagonal blocks divides the next. Do you know how to obtain it in Sage?

Comment: I don't know, I'm sorry. You could try posting on ask.sagemath.org or the "sage-support" Google group.